# Create Object from Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic

I'm using EntityFramework to a list of objects from the database and I'm using Anonymous Types to eventually return the right object. Because there are several functions that has to do this 'Anonymous type conversion' I want to extract this to functions.

I can create a function to create a dynamic but can't create a function that converts a dynamic in a specific type because if the function has a parameter that contains a dynamic, the return type is a dynamic type too.

This works:

```
  List<SomeObject> list = list
            .Select(i => GetAnonymousType(i))
            .Select(i => new SomeObject {Item1 = i.Item1, Item2 =i.Item2}).ToList();
```

This doesn't:

```
List<SomeObject> list = list
         .Select(i => GetAnonymousType(i))
         .Select(i => CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic(i)).ToList();

 private static SomeObject CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic(dynamic i)
 {
     return new SomeObject {Item1 = i.Item1, Item2 = i.Item2};
 }
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zLFlur

Is there a way I can use a function like: CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic to return the right type?

Comment: The problem I guess you've encountered is that EF cannot translate `CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic` into SQL. The only way to solve it, as far as I know, is to do it in memory. Execute your query and then execute the method `CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic`. With the obvious downside that you need to defined a select anyway.. :(

Comment: Even if this were translatable to SQL the problem is that you try to use a time at *compile*-time which you provide at *runtime*. This won´t work at all. You could use reflection to get this to work, but you still won´t get the compile-time type and thus your `Select` will never by strongly typed - which I doubt is even possible (or is there a non-generic select?).

Comment: Casting the dynamic to an object an then creating a new SomeObject using reflection works. I don't know if I will go that will. I better copy the code to convert a dynamic to SomeObject in each function that needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
      list = list
     .Select(i => GetAnonymousType(i))
     .Select(i => CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic(i) as SomeObject).ToList();
```

Comment: That simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code at [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zLFlur), your problem is not with `CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic` method, your problem is with `GetAnonymousType` method. This method returns `dynamic` and .NET cannot handle it. The compliler error says that:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<`dynamic`>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<`SomeObject`>'

Even changing query to

```
list = list
      .Select(i => CreateSomeObjectFromDynamic(GetAnonymousType(i)))
      .ToList();
```

will produce the same error. But, if you change return type of `GetAnonymousType` method to `object` as below:

```
private static object GetAnonymousType(SomeObject i)
{
    return new { Item1 = i.Item1, Item2 = i.Item2 };
}
```

your problem will be solved. But, this works in memory, I am not sure that it will successfully be translated into SQL if you  try to use it with `IQueryable` for example. Also, I do not recomend using `dynamic`, even though it works after chaning return type to `object` your code does not seem right. If you make a bit effort, I am sure that you will find another way, for example using *inheritance*, *generics* and etc.

Comment: This works only if I create SomeObject in GetAnonymousType using reflection.

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra, I do not know what you mean, but copy your code from fiddle, just chagne the return type of `GetAnonymousType` to `object`, uncomment commented lines and it will work